# IEEE references

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

Writing an IEEE paper using bibtex.

Wondering if it is possible to include a small quote from the source *in the bibliography itself.*

The issue is that some refs are informal – blogs, even comments on SE! – and it would be neat if small snippets from some of them could be put in the bibliography alongside the reference.

In addition to the main question above there are one or two side ones:

- Is this legal/allowed?
- Are references in abstract allowed? (this is after the acceptance stage but before final)

---

### Added later

I figured that putting in the bib entry

```
 note = {da de da}
```

puts "da de da" in the generated references, but at the start.  How to get it at end?

Comment: A small quote should be okay if you state that clearly, for example using "". // But references, well, in IEEE proceedings, typically do not use informal sources. (For example, many blogs will point to a book or article. So you may use that source instead.) // There should be no citation in abstract (I know that from IEEE Transactions requirements, but maybe not for IEEE Proceedings), but I did once see one. So It's  better to avoid that.

Comment: So what's the small quote mechanism @TeddyvanJerry? I'm really noob at latex. Pointing a reference that I could read is fine

Comment: I have never seen quotes in bibliography in all IEEE publications. Just put them in the main text with ``this is a quoted sentence'' \cite{xxx}. That should be equivalent. But typically it is good practice to avoid the original sentence by rephrasing it.